# Failed to allocate a 36368142 byte allocation in String Builder

Tags: android, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I am trying to send all the contacts of a mobile phone to my server.
But I am getting out of memory issue while appending huge number of contacts in StringBuffer. So please need suggestion how can this be resolved. Attaching below my chunk of code.

```
    try{

        userContactDetails = new StringBuffer();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, null, null, null);

                StringBuffer singleUserDetail = new StringBuffer();

                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        // Create query to use CommonDataKinds classes to fetch emails
                        Cursor eCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                        + " = " + id, null, null);
                        StringBuffer phoneNos = new StringBuffer("");
                        String emailAddress = "";
                        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);

                            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                phoneNos.append(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))+PHONO_NO_SEPARATOR);
                            }
                            pCur.close();
                        }

                        while (eCur.moveToNext()) {

                            // This would allow you get several email addresses
                            emailAddress = eCur
                                    .getString(eCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                            //Log.i("SyncContacts", "Email=="+emailAddress);
                        }
                        eCur.close();
                        if(!phoneNos.toString().equals("")){    // phono not null
                            singleUserDetail.append(name);
                            singleUserDetail.append(CONTACT_ITEMS_SEPARATOR);
                            singleUserDetail.append(phoneNos.substring(0,phoneNos.length()-1));
                        }
                        if(phoneNos.toString().equals("") && !emailAddress.equals("")){ // phone no null and email not null
                            singleUserDetail.append(name);
                            singleUserDetail.append(CONTACT_ITEMS_SEPARATOR);
                            singleUserDetail.append(emailAddress);
                        }
                        if(!phoneNos.toString().equals("") && !emailAddress.equals("")){
                            singleUserDetail.append(CONTACT_ITEMS_SEPARATOR);
                            singleUserDetail.append(emailAddress);
                        }
                        if(!singleUserDetail.toString().equals("")){
                            userContactDetails.append(singleUserDetail);
                            userContactDetails.append(CONTACTS_SEPARATOR);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!userContactDetails.toString().equals("")) {
                }

            }
        });
        t1.start();

    }catch(Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("SyncContacts", "Server not called : " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: If you really want to have it all together and send it in one go, why not write it into a file using a FileOutputStream. You can then upload the file to the server.

Comment: Writing it into a file ? You don't feel it will be heavy operation to make a file and than upload it using multipart request

Comment: That's up to you. But since you're already doing network IO, I don't think including file IO here is a big problem.

Comment: 36MB??? how many contacts do you have?